# Complemented subspace constructed from finite pieces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $Y=\overline{\cup E_n}$ is a closed subspace of a Banach space, where each $E_n$ is a $n$-dimensional subspace, $K$-complemented in $X$, and for any $n$, $E_n\subseteq E_{n+1}$. Can one conclude that $Y$ is complemented in $X$?

Comment: Why the Hilbert spaces tag? The question is trivially yes for Hilbert spaces

Comment: Removed Hilbert space tag, indeed irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $X=\ell_\infty({\bf N})$ and take $E_n = \operatorname{span}(e_1,\dots, e_n)$. Then $Y=c_0({\bf N})$ which is well-known – by a non-trivial argument – to be uncomplemented in $X$ (in the sense of Banach spaces). Look up "Phillips's Lemma".

Comment: Thank you. Do you also have a separable example?

Comment: I can't think of one off the top of my head

Comment: Thank you, maybe I will post a separate question.